# Python fuzzywuzzy поиск по словарю

Tags: python, словарь

подскажите как реализовать поиск по ключам в словаре но выдавать в результате значение словаря, использя fuzzywuzzy. У библиотеки есть метод process, ищущий совпадения в списке. Но он не работает со словарем. Есть код выводящий самый подходящий результат, но мне нужны все возможные результаты чтобы выбрать самые подходящие по score.
Любая подсказка будет полезна, благодарю!

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

information_code = {
'ярлык приложение смарт теминал': 'После установки приложения в личном кабинете ярлык отобразится на экране в зависимости от функционала.\
Подробную информацию вы можете посмотреть в описании приложения.',
'выгрузка данных приложение': 'Выгрузка данных из приложения обычно происходит автоматически раз в час.',
'терминал ккт регистрация': 'Чтобы зарегестрировать ККТ необходимо нажать на терминал....'
}

user_input_information = 'терминал'
close_match = max(information_code, key=lambda x: fuzz.token_ratio(x, user_input_information))

#print(close_match)
print(information_code[close_match])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from functools import partial

data_dict = {
    'ярлык приложение смарт теминал': 'После установки приложения в личном кабинете ярлык отобразится на экране в '
                                      'зависимости от функционала. Подробную информацию вы можете посмотреть в '
                                      'описании приложения.',
    'выгрузка данных приложение': 'Выгрузка данных из приложения обычно происходит автоматически раз в час.',
    'терминал ккт регистрация': 'Чтобы зарегестрировать ККТ необходимо нажать на терминал....'
}
input_str = 'терминал'

f = partial(fuzz.partial_ratio, input_str)

for k in data_dict:
    print(data_dict[k], f(k))
```

Если я правильно понял, что вы хотите получить в результате, то вывод в данном случае выглядит так:

```
После установки приложения в личном кабинете ярлык отобразится на экране в зависимости от функционала. Подробную информацию вы можете посмотреть в описании приложения. 93
Выгрузка данных из приложения обычно происходит автоматически раз в час. 31
Чтобы зарегестрировать ККТ необходимо нажать на терминал.... 100
```

Comment: Благодарю! это хорошее решение